# How does the threading.Timer() and time.sleep() behave in Python with relation to multiprocessing?

Tags: python-2.7, sleep, python-multiprocessing

I have a Mongo Database with several collections that stores count values in an array from high frequency data sources. These collections all have the same schema. I'm trying to model these count values in an incremental fashion. For example, there could be 200 count values in a collection when I start processing it. I am going to process this 200 element array incrementally, i.e., first two elements, first three elements, first four elements, and so on.

Since I have different accounts, I use the multiprocessing module to create a separate process for every collection. I cannot use the 'threading' module as scipy is not thread-safe. Since the original data sources are streaming data sources, the count array will be growing in size. To be able to continuously process this growing array, I make each process go to sleep and then start up again. I used:

1. threading.Timer() to do this. However, this did not work as instead of going to sleep the processes would simply end.
2. time.sleep() to put the processes to sleep. However, with time.sleep(), after a point of time, the value being output keeps being repeated in essence meaning that the array is not being processed after a while.

Any help on why this could be happening is much appreciated.

Edit: I'm not using multi-threading for the parallelization. I'm using the multiprocessing module from Python. Every process works on a different Mongo collection and is independent of the other.

Comment: What's your input stream? you shouldn't put your threads to sleep, make them wait for the input stream and leave the thread management to the OS. 
`I cannot use the 'threading' module as scipy is not thread-safe` Why not? If you're not sharing anything between the threads, you don't need to care about thread safety.

Comment: @xvan: I don't directly access the input stream. All I access is a MongoDB database. I cannot use threads because despite the fact that the threads do not share any data, the scipy library is not thread-safe. Refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612213/python-threading-curve-fit-null-argument-to-internal-routine